# Extract data from PDF file with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I'm trying to pull some data from a large PDF file in VB.Net I found the following code [online](http://www.ehow.com/how_6199098_use-_amp_-print-pdf-file.html), but it's not helping:

```
Sub PrintPDF (strPDFFileName as string)
    Dim sAdobeReader as String
    'This is the full path to the Adobe Reader or Acrobat application on your computer
     sAdobeReader = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 6.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
     RetVal = Shell(sAdobeReader & "/P" & Chr(34) & sStrPDFFileName & Chr(34), 0)
End Sub
```

I'm really lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

/P will just display load the file and display the Print dialog - dead end.

You will probably need a library of some sort to get to the contents of the PDF.

If the file has a very simple structure you maybe able to extract the data just by reading the bytes. See if you can open it with a file like Notepad++ and see the contents.

BTW VS2010 has several editors for looking at/editing files:
File, Open File... pick the file then use the dropdown on the Open button.